Redundant serving of web application without loadbalancer?
I want to run a web application inside a mobile app using WebView. The web application uses IndexedDB for saving various important values. I like to make the web application very available (redundant). I already have three webservers with public IP adresses on three different hosting locations and I can use them for that purpose.
What I considered:

I cannot use three subdomains for the three servers. That would have been my preferred solution as the WebView app can first check the availability of one of the three subdomains randomly and then submit a working subdomain to the WebView url. But IndexedDB content is bound to the full domain and so its content will be gone if the domain changes.
I cannot use DNS-Round-Robin because if one server fails, 33% of the users get error messages (server not answering). Due to my research, WebView does not try multiple IPs from DNS if one fails. And I also found, it even keeps it cached (does not try another one for a longer time).
I don't want to use a loadbalancer because its application and host will become a single point of failure even with my three servers behind. Also, as for DNS-Round-Robin, if one fails the users get error messages.
I cannot use the IPs directly, as the https wildcard certificate is for domain names only.

Any other ideas on how to solve such a problem?

You don’t have to operate your own load balancer though, many CDNs can be configured as load balancer, for example https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/ - Or rather than static round robin DNS you can have an health check routine add/remove IP-addresses from your DNS record when servers come up or become unavailable. With a short DNS TTL that can work well enough in many use cases. - There are probably other solutions as well. - But architecture and design recommendations aren’t really on-topic for ServerFault as they are much more likely to result in opinions rather than answers.

Thanks @HBruijn I first asked this on Stackoverflow, but they told me to ask that here instead...
I wonder if there are other options I have. I already thought about some (listened in my question) but I believe there are more options? For example, I think about skipping IndexedDB and use some App based settings functions to make option 1 work (multiple sub-domains and the app first checks them for availability).
